Use android webview to login twitter
I'm using webview in android to load twitter page: https://twitter.com/home with the following settings:
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Pixel 3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Mobile Safari/537.36");
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(1);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

the page can be load correctly. But when I click on "sign in with google", it goes to an blank page with this url: https://accounts.google.com/gsi/select?client_id=49625052041-kgt0hghf445lmcmhijv46b715m2mpbct.apps.googleusercontent.com&ux_mode=popup&as=xVCsavuJpVfpLyIvDdAAuA&channel_id=7ad0bf9b855bd4daededdcaaf07fe2144c1ccfbd786ddee3f8b8c93dcd859e33&origin=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com.
The error message of this page is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')" from m=credential_page_library:243.
The funny thing is when I paste this URL directly on chrome, it throws the same error with a blank page. But if I use other browsers like edge or safari, it loads the google sign in page correctly.
But webview is using chrome library. It could be related with the iframe used by twitter page or cross site settings.
Can anyone help? Thanks you!
I have tried all different settings of webview. Tried to enable multiplewindow. All didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
